# How to register an attribute to Woocommerce programmatically

Tags: woocommerce

I'm not talking about adding an attribute to a product but I want to add an attribute itself..

You can do that from the UI under Products -> Attributes but from the code how is it done (e.i: what functions to call or tables to update)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An attribute is merely a custom taxonomy, so I think you should be able to do this the same as you'd register any custom taxonomy. WooCommerce prefaces their attributes taxonomy names with 'pa_' (probably standing for product attibute)

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_attribute' );

function create_product_attribute() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'pa_genre',
        'product',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Genre' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: After adding this code, I see the 'Genre' under Products left menu under Categories and Tags. I need to create new attribute while filling products using an API. What is wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A comment on a 3 year old post is not the appropriate place to ask a question. Please create your own detailed, specific question.